# Diff + patch - Sum instead of replace

Tags: bash, diff, patch

Say I have a file A, which contains this:

> a = 5

And a file B, like this:

> b = 5

Now, it's obvious that diff will produce something like this (the patch):

> 1c1
>
> *<* a = 5
>
> *---*
>
> *>*  b = 5

Patching file A will obviously replace its contents with those of file B, resulting in file A containing

> b = 5

What I want to do, however, is different. I want the contents of files A and B to merge, so that after patching file A it will contain

> a = 5
>
> b = 5

My case if course way more complex than my example but I think I've figured it out except for the summative diff/patch at the end.

tl;dr: I want the diff/patch to sum rather than replace the differences in the files. How can I do that?

Comment: This is not what diff and patch are for. You will need to use an actual tool that supports merges.

Comment: Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Not really. I leave it to my VCS to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to patch some files, you are trying to merge them. There are lot's of tools out there that will help you, e.g. take a look at `kdiff`!

**Edit**:
Some more tools:

- meld
- gPyFm
- diff3
- tkdiff
- P4Merge

At least `vim -d` will do the job ;-)

Comment: The problem with kdiff is that it requires the whole kde base, which is quite heavy considering that I do most of my work on CLI. I installed meld but when I tell it to merge, it does the same as diff+patch.

Comment: of course each tool has its dependencies.. since i don't know your env i can't recommend anything based on this. but i know that `kdiff3` does a really good job. nevertheless i added some more programs, maybe you'll find some more...

Answer (score 0):

You tell very very little about what problem you are trying to solve (or you talk too much about how the approach you took did not work). What's more interesting is what you want done.

Perhaps you could be done with

```
sort -u A B
```

Because it will give the output you require with the inputs you provide.

Answer (score 0):

The diff command from the GNU diffutils packages provides an option to merge two different files by inserting `#ifdef` preprocessor instructions. For instance consider 2 files `f1` and `f2` (displayed side-by-side):

```
line 1     |   line 1
line 2     |   line 2
line 3a    |   line 3a
line 4     |   line 4
line 5a    |   line 5a
```

Calling `diff -D MARKER f1 f2` will produce this merged output:

```
line 1
line 2
#ifndef MARKER
line 3a
#else /* MARKER */
line 3b
#endif /* MARKER */
line 4
#ifndef MARKER
line 5a
#else /* MARKER */
line 5c
#endif /* MARKER */
```

You can strip the preprocessor instructions to get a clean merged file, e.g. by using `grep`:

```
diff -D MARKER f1 f2 | grep -v "MARKER"
```

Note that the token `MARKER` must not exist in the original input files, so you should better use something more special, e.g. a random token like `c11ced4751ef4b3aa60e512bdaa184210441b4ed0`.